# "Restrict Background data" with Jelly Bean on tf300t ASUS tablet

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, battery-life, processes, background-data

On my tf300t ASUS tablet (with wifi only) I tried to set "Restrict Background Data" following

*Settings->Data Usage->three boxes in the upper right corner*,

but there is no such option. I read on some forums that this option is only available with limited mobile data, but the option to set a limit is not available under Settings->Data Usage->three boxes in the upper right corner.

There is, however, an option under

*Settings ->Developer Options -> Background process limit*,

but I'm not sure about it. On my Gingerbread phone, background processes were disabled, and whenever I wanted to download an app, I had to enable it. With the Backround Process limit, however, downloading is possible (therefore, I'm not sure if this is the equivalent to Gingerbread's setting). Furthermore, I noticed that, after setting Background Process limit, every once in a while I get a message that some Asus process has been terminated. My question is: how would one disable background processes (no connections to wifi while screen off, ...) in order to save the battery?

Comment: Maybe that option is not available in wifi only tablets. Usually you restrict data because you have limited data on your mobile plan, where wifi you (usually) don't have that limit.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the background process limit box. Its the best way to limit your background processes and in a way save your battery. You can also use power saving mode if you have one....

Answer (score 1):

On my HTC Wildfire (Buzz) running Android 4.0.4 I find the corresponding option in *Settings→Data Usage*, when I hit the "Menu" button. This brings up A sub-menu with 4 checkboxes: Data-Roaming, Background Data, Show WiFi, Linear Scale. Tapping the "Background data" option I am informed:

> background data only can be limited if you defined an overall limit for mobile data

(well, I have not defined any limit there yet). So that should be where background data can be restricted.